# Java: 2d array totals not completing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sum

This is a school project. It is to display the info from the array into a tubular format with totals on the right side and across the bottom for each row and column. It does all the totals except one row. I can't find where the problem is. Can anyone help?!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
//program uses class Scanner

    public class Ex6_20
    {
      //method begins java application
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        //create Scanner to obtain imput
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int monthySales=0; //varible to hold mothly sales
        int productNum; //varible to hold product number
        int salesNum=0; //varible to hold saleperson number
        int totalSales=0; //varible to hold total sales
        int []totalProduct = {0,0,0,0,0};//build array to hold total product
        int []salesTotal = {0,0,0,0,0};//build array to hold total salesperson

        // Build array to hold sales information by salesperson and poduct
        int[][]sales = {{2000,1500,500,800,0},
                        {500,2200,600,1000,0},
                        {1000,2000,300,2100,0},
                        {2500,4000,400,3000,0},
                        {300,3200,500,2300,0},
                        {0,0,0,0}};

        //figure total by product
        for(int row =0; row < sales.length; row++)
        {
          for(int column = 0; column < sales[row].length; column++)
            totalProduct[column] += sales[row][column];
        }//end for

        //figure total by salesperson
        for(int column = 0; column < sales.length; column++)
        {
     for(int row = 0; row < sales[column].length; row++)
     salesTotal[row] += sales[column][row];
        }//end for

        //fill totals for product
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
    sales[i][4] = totalProduct[i];
        }//end for

        //fill totals for salesperson
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
    sales[5][i] = salesTotal[i];
        }//end for

     // print info from array in table format
     for(int row =0; row < sales.length; row++)
        {
          for(int column = 0; column < sales[row].length; column++)
          System.out.print(sales[row][column]+"\t");
         System.out.println();

        }//end for
      } //end main method
    } //end class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

If you swap the variable names "row" and "column" in "figure total by salesperson" you'll notice that you are actually doing exactly the same calculation as "figure total by product", just with misleading variable names.  (You're using column as the row index, and vice versa.)  As of now, both totalProduct and salesTotal contain identical values, which is not right.

That is the main problem.

Also, when you display sales total and product totals, they are actually swapped.  I suspect this is because you mean to have a total product per row with totalProduct[row] += ... and a total sales per column with salesTotal[column] += ..., but maybe the names are just swapped and the row/column indices are ok.

I'd actually recommend removing the extra sum fields from the sales array so all of the rows have the same number of columns and using hard-coded array bounds to start with, in order to make it more obvious what's happening until you get the sums correct.  Then once the sums come up right, you can go back and make it work more generally. Otherwise, you may keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions without it being obvious why, which is how I suspect you ended up with this solution so far.

For example, you could start with something very straightforward like this, then go back and make it a lot nicer and more general so it can work with different array sizes:

```
    int[][] table = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } };

    int[] rowSums = new int[3];
    int[] colSums = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            rowSums[i] += table[i][j];
            colSums[j] += table[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            System.out.print('\t');
        }
        System.out.println(rowSums[i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print(colSums[j]);
        System.out.print('\t');
    }
    System.out.println();
```